# Breakpoints in Java file not getting detected during ANT Build

Tags: java, ant

I am having  a code like one below.

```
package com.mugil.servlet2;

public class Sample
{
    static
    {
      System.out.println("Hi There");
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
      System.out.println("Sample Output1");
      System.out.println("Sample Output2");
    }
}
```

I am initiating a ANT build script by the script below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="ANT2" default="copyTarget">
  <target name="copyTarget">
  <mkdir dir="test/classes/"/>
  <javac srcdir="src/com/mugil/servlet2/" destdir="test/classes/" includeantruntime="false"></javac>
    <java classname="com.mugil.servlet2.Sample">
    <classpath path="test/classes/"></classpath>
     </java>
   </target>
</project>
```

I have added debugger at first line of static block and in main block 
[image]

When I do the ANT build I am unable to have control in Java Breakpoints.

Thanks for Reply.

Comment: A build is not a run!

Comment: @Smutje But you can execute `java` commands from ant

Comment: Is there a Way to stop at breakpoints in Java File

Comment: i guess you should first know why is ANT used for and what can be done with it. It is nowhere related to breakpoints in your code. and you cannot have breakpoints for code inside a jar. put the breakpoints in th ide code for debugging purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breakpoints don't exist in Java source code at all - nor even in the compiled class files. They're purely a debug-time feature - the debugger instructs the VM where the breakpoints are. The breakpoints you're seeing in your IDE are stored in an IDE-specific fashion; they're not expected to be persisted with the source code.

What *does* matter in terms of compile-time information is the line numbers - if you don't include those in the class file, then clearly any line-based breakpoints can't be installed when you try to debug the code.

Comment: Thanks for Replying.What we do in out project is use xml File for generating Beans by calling BeanGenerator.java which reads XML file and generates beans accordingly.This Process Happens through ANT codegen file.Is there a way track the parts of code while doing this.That is while running ANT Script.

Comment: @JavaBeginner: I don't know what you mean by "track the parts of code". If you're running something as part of your build and it's going wrong, then *either* just add more diagnostics, *or* run that code manually within a debugger and debug it that way.

Answer (score 2):

You need to provide the information which allows a debugger to attach to the running JVM

For example...

```
<java dir="${target.dir}" jar="${run.jar}" fork="true" jvm="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" taskname="java1.6">
    <jvmarg value="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=${suspend.debug},address=${remote.debug.port}"/>
</java>
```

This will then allow you to attach a "remote" debugger to the JVM on the specified port, this is where your IDE comes in...

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are running the compiled java-coding.
Eclipse debugger isn't available here...